# How do I create a new git branch with the difference of two branches?

Tags: git, version-control

I have my `master` branch of my project.  And I also have a branch, `adding-charts`, that has many changes, new files, modifications, etc. from the `master` branch.  I'm wanting to create a new branch `new-feature` that has tracked the files that are different from the two branches but not committed yet.

I can see the differences by doing... `git diff --name-status master adding-charts`

And what I would expect is to have a new branch where those either show under "Changes to be committed" or "Untracked files" when doing `git status`.  My thinking is this way I can modify and correctly commit/merge them back to the `master` branch.

If this isn't the correct process in which to make my changes, please let me know as well. Thanks

**Edit**

So, I've used git before in a very basic form- and by explaining it, perhaps it will make a little more sense in how I got where I am and what I'm trying to do.

Usually, I would do work on a feature and add/commit/push from my `master` branch.  If I had any features I was working on I just wouldn't add or commit them at the time I wanted to publish a change to my web application, and I would continue to work on them until they were completed.

Recently my guest VM started to have issues so I committed everything to my repository under a new branch name and pushed it up to my github account. I think cloned it back to the new VM I built recently.  I figured this was a good time to develop a new workflow.  I've read any time I want to add a new feature that I should create a new branch and then merge/publish it once it's complete.  So that's what I intend to do moving forward, but am trying to clean it up now. `adding-charts` was a branch that incorporated a few new features actually.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Isn't `new-feature` dependent on `adding-charts`, thus should sit ontop of that branch?

Comment: @NilsWerner, Added an edit to my original post as I figure it might clear up the situation a little bit... or I hope it does.

Comment: So `adding-charts` is done and you want all of it to end up in `master`?

Answer (score 4):

I would do this instead (but please, read all steps before beginning):

1. Make sure you don't have anything not committed (`git stash` or `git commit` could help you here)
2. Make a note of where you are, in case things go wrong: `git rev-parse adding-charts` will give you a nice reference
3. Rebase adding-charts on top of master (`git checkout adding-charts; git rebase master`)
4. Now, you can `git reset master` to get all modifications in the staging area. (Note that this will throw away all your commit messages, you can get these later but I won't include it here.) Feel free to `git add`, `git reset HEAD -- filename` and then `git commit` as much as you want to. Begin with the files that already exists in master (i.e. `git status` and look for files not prefixed with "new file").
5. Now that you have all your commits in order, you can `git checkout master` and `git merge XYZ` where XYZ is the latest commit in the adding-charts branch with changes only to your old files. `git log -p adding-charts` can help you find XYZ here
6. After master is updated, you can `git push master` (I assume the reason for your question is to keep working on adding-charts whilst sharing your changes on master)
7. To keep working on adding-charts, you could `git checkout adding-charts` and `git rebase master`

If anything goes wrong or you change your mind:

- `git rebase --abort` if you are in the middle of a rebase
- `git checkout adding-charts; git reset --hard XYZ` where XYZ is the result of `git rev-parse` in step 2 above. This will make all of this process undone.